# Why does following lots of symlinks get slow quick?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, ubuntu-16.04

I have a directory with ~2 million symlinks that point to real files on the same drive, which is a real local hard disk (it's not a network mount). The file names are all unique and the files they point to are scattered among different directories but they all share the same parent path. I'm consolidating files in multiple directories using symlinks.

```
/some/full/path/consolidated/my_file -> /some/full/path/mydir2/my_file
/some/full/path/consolidated/my_file2 -> /some/full/path/mydir3/my_file2
/some/full/path/consolidated/my_file3 -> /some/full/path/mydir4/my_file3
/some/full/path/consolidated/my_file4 -> /some/full/path/mydir4/my_file4
/some/full/path/consolidated/my_file5 -> /some/full/path/mydir2/my_file5
/some/full/path/consolidated/my_file6 -> /some/full/path/mydir3/my_file6
```

The symlinks are guaranteed to not be broken.

The problem is that

```
time find "/some/full/path/consolidated/" -maxdepth 1 -type l -print > /tmp/foo
```

finishes quickly:

```
1.24 user 0.83 system 0:02.08elapsed
```

However,

```
time find -L "/some/full/path/consolidated/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print > /tmp/foo
```

followed by

```
watch wc -l /tmp/foo
```

shows that it gets to ~660,000 lines very quickly, and then it stalls out, adding a few thousand results every now and again.

Why might it stall? And is it possible to make the second command as quick as the first one?

Edit:
`/tmp` doesn't show up in `mount` at all (so I assume it's not a tmpfs). According to htop I'm not low on memory; I have about 50GB free. CPU usage is also low. For `find -L path`, which stalls, `/tmp/foo` is about 90MB when the slowdown occurs. For `find path`, which doesn't stall, `/tmp/foo` is 111MB.

I have the same slowdown when redirecting output to ~/foo.

Edit:
When eyeballing `iotop`, `find -L` lists an I/O of 99.99%, but only after about 10 seconds, which is well after the normal `find` would finish.

Comment: What do the symlinks point to? Other symlinks? Files within other mounts? Non-existing paths? All of these? If you were to write a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this should be much easier to debug.

Comment: They point to real files.

Comment: I added some clarifying examples to the question, but I'm not really sure how to post a minimal example of symlinks when the issue arises with an obscene number of symlinks; I'll try to add any additional information though.

Comment: You could easily enough create a whole bunch of symlinks in a directory and remove the directory afterwards.

Comment: What is the size of the file `/tmp/foo` in both cases? `/tmp` might be a tmpfs system, but for large files it might cost time to allocate extra space, especially if your system is low on memory. How much memory do you have? Can you try outputting to a "normal" directory and see whether the time difference is still apparent?

Comment: `/tmp` doesn't show up in `mount` as a tmpfs. According to htop I'm not low on memory; I have about 50GB free. For `find -L path`, which stalls, `/tmp/foo` is about 90MB when the slowdown occurs. For `find path`, which doesn't stall, `/tmp/foo` is 111MB.

Comment: Missed the second part of your question at first, sorry: Redirecting to ~/foo has the same slowdown at around 90MB.

Answer (score 0):

try to increase your inode cache with

```
echo 50 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
```

value 100 is average, lower values = bigger inode+dentry cache
downside: a larger cache [can be slower](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Linux%20Kernel%20Tuning/#vmvfs_cache_pressure), so you can also try to decrease your cache with

```
echo 200 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
```

or you can use a cached file list with

```
sudo updatedb
locate /some/full/path/consolidated
```

also keep an eye on inode usage, symlinks occupy inodes (hardlinks too)

```
df -i
```

related: https://serverfault.com/questions/338097/tuning-linux-cache-settings-for-inode-caching

more on disk tuning: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching/41831

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to the dataset or the system anymore. Hopefully your answer can help someone else though!